# Audio Recording Script not working on WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have the following code on WSL2 with Ubuntu:

```
import pyaudio,wave

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 2
fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
seconds = 3
filename = "output.wav"
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

print('Recording')

stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)

frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames
for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

print('Finished recording')
wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
wf.setframerate(fs)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

However, when I run the code, I get bunch of ALSA errors and it seems like WSL2 is not recognizing my microphone:

[image]

I am unsure if WSL2 has built in audio support as there aren't many examples of recording audio from a script. How can I fix these errors and make WSL2 record audio from my python script?

Answer (score 1):

WSL2 doesn't have direct access to most hardware devices, so it's no surprise that mic access is failing.

That said, there are *some* ways to access certain hardware devices through WSL2.  One of these is through USB/IP, to share a Windows USB device through to WSL2/Linux.

I've used USB/IP, but never for this particular purpose, so I can't say for sure that it will work, but I expect it to.  In theory, you will need a USB microphone installed in *Windows* and to then share that USB device via [USB/IP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb).

You should be able to access the device through PyAudio with that in place.